# Why a hover state doesn't work with Safari?

Tags: html, css

In the snippet below, when I hover over the defined area in Safari, I'm not getting the hover state. If you view this code in Chrome, the hover state works fine (on hover, the play button turns blue).

**Why doesn't the hover state work as expected in Safari?**

```js
try {
  document.body.querySelector(":focus-visible");
} catch (error) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src =
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/focus-visible@5.2.0/dist/focus-visible.min.js";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
  alert("Button was clicked.");
});
```

```css
.wistia {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.wistia__overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.wistia::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
}
.wistia button.embed-youtube__play {
  background: url("https://nextiva.com/assets/svg/play-button.svg") no-repeat center center, rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.8);
  background-size: 40%;
  background-position: 55%;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s;
  width: 10%;
  height: 13%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
.wistia:hover button.embed-youtube__play,
.wistia button.embed-youtube__play:focus-visible {
  background: url("https://nextiva.com/assets/svg/play-button.svg") no-repeat center center, #005fec;
  background-size: 40%;
  background-position: 55%;
}
.wistia_embed,
.wistia embed,
.wistia iframe {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

button:focus-visible,
a:focus-visible,
a:focus-visible::after,
input[type=checkbox]:focus-visible,
input[type=radio]:focus-visible,
input[type=submit]:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px solid #005FEC;
  outline-offset: 4px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="wistia">
  <button class="embed-youtube__play"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like people have been having problems with Safari lately, not sure whys that...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it looks like, that it's still not supported yet: https://caniuse.com/css-focus-visible.

Why do you need and want to use the pseudo-class `focus-visible` instead of `focus`? What's the advantage for you or the user (here)?

Replace the focus-visible with focus and (if it looks appropiate for you) remove those two properties for the play-button.

```
outline: 2px solid #005FEC;
outline-offset: 4px;
```

It works fine.

Comment: You need to read up on the differences. `focus` allows the focus state to display on click and when navigated to with a keyboard. `focus-visible` let's the user get the focus state on keyboard navigation, but not on click. I have a specific reason for needing `focus-visible`. The Javascript fallback I provided in my OP is designed to provide the `focus-visible` state in browsers that don't support it.